# What is the best possible way to find the first AND the last occurrences of an element in a list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, find-occurrences

The basic way I usually use is by using the list.index(element) and reversed_list.index(element), but this fails when I need to search for many elements and the length of the list is too large say 10^5 or say 10^6 or even larger than that. What is the best possible way (which uses very little time) for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, someone needs to do the work in finding the element, and in a large list this can take time! Without more information or a code example, it'll be difficult to help you, but usually the go-to answer is to use another data structure- for example, if you can keep your elements in a dictionary instead of a list with the key being the element and the value being an array of indices, you'll be much quicker.

Comment: I forgot to use the dictionary. Making two dictionaries one each for the first and the last index worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can build auxiliary lookup structures:

```
lst = [1,2,3,1,2,3] # super long list

last = {n: i for i, n in enumerate(lst)}
first = {n: i for i, n in reversed(list(enumerate(lst)))}
last[3]
# 5
first[3]
# 2
```

The construction of the lookup dicts takes linear time, but then the lookup itself is constant.
Whreas calls to `list.index()` take linear time, and repeatedly doing so is then quadratic (given the number of lookups you make depends on the size of the list).

You could also build a single structure in one iteration:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lookup = defaultdict(lambda: [None, None])

for i, n in enumerate(lst):
    lookup[n][1] = i
    if lookup[n][0] is None:
        lookup[n][0] = i
    

lookup[3]
# [2, 5]
lookup[2]
# [1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just remember first and last index for every element in the list:

```
In [9]: l = [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(100)]

In [10]: first_index = {}

In [11]: last_index = {}

In [12]: for idx, x in enumerate(l):
    ...:     if x not in first_index:
    ...:         first_index[x] = idx
    ...:     last_index[x] = idx
    ...:


In [13]: [(x, first_index.get(x), last_index.get(x)) for x in range(1, 11)]
Out[13]:
[(1, 3, 88),
 (2, 23, 90),
 (3, 10, 91),
 (4, 13, 98),
 (5, 11, 57),
 (6, 4, 99),
 (7, 9, 92),
 (8, 19, 95),
 (9, 0, 77),
 (10, 2, 87)]

In [14]: l[0]
Out[14]: 9
```

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand what does this code does (I am asking for a large number of elements to be searched in a very large lengthed list). As @maor10 pointed, making two dictionaries one each for the first and the last index worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach sounds good, I did some testing and:

```
import numpy as np

long_list = list(np.random.randint(0, 100_000, 100_000_000))

# This takes 10ms in my machine
long_list.index(999)

# This takes 1,100ms in my machine
long_list[::-1].index(999)

# This takes 1,300ms in my machine
list(reversed(long_list)).index(999)

# This takes 200ms in my machine
long_list.reverse()
long_list.index(999)
long_list.reverse()
```

But at the end of the day, a Python list does not seem like the best data structure for this.

As others have sugested, you can build a dict:

```
indexes = {}
for i, val in enumerate(long_list):
    if val in indexes.keys():
        indexes[val].append(i)
    else:
        indexes[val] = [i]
```

This is memory expensive, but solves your problem (depends on how often you modify the original list).

You can then do:

```
# This takes 0.02ms in my machine
ix = indexes.get(999)
ix[0], ix[-1]
```